# My post requests are pending when multiple POST requests occur

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When submitting my forms via AJAZ post, some POST requests remains in status pending(en attente=pending). This problem only occurs on my laptop!

I noticed that when I have a unique posted request (at the same time) I have no problems. Only when I have multiple posted requests problems occurs.

[image]

All these pending POST command are "remote validations" triggered when submitting the form.

I have uninstalled antivirus and deactivated my firewall, but that showed no change.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot and solve this problem?

---

**UPDATE**

As requested, here are more informations:

**Does it work in Visual Studio debugging on that machine?** When debugging in VS I have the same problem.

**What happens when you set a breakpoint within those methods?** When I set a breakpoints, these are not reached.

**How many browsers have you tried?** I try with IE9, GC, Safari. I have problem with all of these.

**Which OS is the problem machine?** Win 7 Family Premium 64 bits.

Comment: Does it work in Visual Studio debugging on that machine? What happens when you set a breakpoint within those methods? How many browsers have you tried? Which OS is the problem machine?

Comment: Could you show your code? A narrowed down version of your model, view and controller allowing to reproduce the problem would be great.

Comment: As Darin suggests, please edit your question to include your view and controller. The problem sounds like it's related to multiple concurrent requests from the client.

Comment: Ok I'll first try to uninstall MVC3 and MVC4 framework from my computer and reinstall MVC3 only. If it doesn't solve my problem, I'll update my question to include more informations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to **session state locking** ...
In your controller add this `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]`

and *optionally* inherit from  `AsyncController`

worked for me with asp.net mvc 4.